# Typing annotate a `njit()`-decorated function accepting another function as parameter

Tags: python, function, numba, mypy, python-typing

Assume I have the following **toy** example:

```py
import typing as _T


def foo(fn: _T.Callable[[int, int], int]) -> int:
    return fn(0, 1)
```

Now, for some reason I want to accelerate `foo()` with Numba in Non-Python mode:

```py
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def foo_nb(fn: _T.Callable[[int, int], int]) -> int:
    return fn(0, 1)
```

However, this no longer captures the fact that `fn` now needs to be compatible with Numba.

**What should I replace `_T.Callable[[int, int], int]` with?**

I could use a string like `"nb.njit(callable)[[int, int], int]"` but I suspect there is something better.

---

Clearly, `_T.Callable[[int, int], int]` is wrong, since passing a normal Python callable will result in an error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at <ipython-input-21-6068134a3c84> (16)
    ....
This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 1: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

---

The result of `type(foo_nb)` is `numba.core.registry.CPUDispatcher` but I am unsure it serves well for documenting the type I should pass to `fn_nb` in `foo_nb()`.

---

I know that `mypy` will fail to work for Numba-accelerated and `@`-decorated functions, as per [this issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7424).

---

A minimal example follows:

```
import typing as _T
import numba as nb


def foo_nb(fn: _T.Callable[[int, int], int]) -> int:
    return fn(0, 1)


def f_nb(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b


foo_nb = nb.njit(foo_nb)
f_nb = nb.njit(f_nb)


foo_nb(f_nb)
foo_nb(lambda x, y: x + y)
# `mypy` will not detect an issue, but the running this code will fail
foo_nb(1)
# error: Argument 1 to "foo_nb" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Callable[[int, int], int]"
```

Comment: What are the types in practice? Please provide a minimal working example. AFAIK Numba does not care about mypy types. So changing `_T.Callable[[int, int], int]` should have no impact on the result. The problem is the way you call the Numba function which is not provided in the question.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I know that the `mypy` has troubles with `numba`, but a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72982778/5218354) seems to be to use the JIT decorators without the `@`-syntax. Anyway I provide a minimal example where `mypy` is happy, but Python is not. I am more looking for some way of documenting this more explicitly, given the poor support for `typing` in Numba.

Comment: The type of a Numba function should be `numba.core.registry.CPUDispatcher`. So you can check if the type is this one. That being said MyPy complain about the Numba import on my machine. Note that Numba functions can have multiple prototypes and you cannot check them unless MyPy have a special support of Numba which appear not to be the case. It also looks like Numba does not support well MyPy.

Comment: I'm not sure what their status is in `mypy` development (rejected? in progress? maybe someday?), but this would be a good use of intersection types. `def foo_nb(fn: Intersect[CPUDispatcher, _T.Callable[...]]) -> int:`. This conveys that the argument must have *both* types (in contrast with `Union`, which only requires a value to have *one* of the types).

Comment: (To be clear, neither `typing` nor `mypy` currently has any support for intersection types, though it might be possible to simulate them via subclassing, generics, protocols, etc.)

Comment: The poor support of typing in Numba is mainly because the type system of Numba does not mach well with the one of Python and in fact this is something many developers have reported in the past. The current Python typing system is bad. Eg. PyPy developers complained about it for their JIT too: they said that it is ["almost entirely useless" for speeding up PyPy](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#would-type-annotations-help-pypy-s-performance). Cython got the same issue and ended up with ugly non-standard annotations. The current solution of Python looks like [this](https://xkcd.com/927/).