# Why Mypy does not work with Numba `@` decorator, but does when called afterwards?

Tags: python, numba, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following script:

```py
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def f1(x: int) -> int:
    return 2 * x


def f2(x: int) -> int:
    return 2 * x


f2 = nb.njit(f2)


f1(1)
f1(1.0)

f2(1)
f2(1.0)
# error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "float"; expected "int"
```

When running `mypy` on this script, an error is found for `f2(1.0)`, but not for `f1(1.0)`. **Why?**

The difference between the two functions is in how they are decorated:

- `f1()` with the [`@`-syntax](https://peps.python.org/pep-0318/#current-syntax)
- `f2()` with the the *equivalent* (?) explicit calling syntax

Comment: Apparently the decorator masks the function's signature. The decorator is replacing the actual function with a completely different function, whose signature could be anything…

Comment: It looks like so, as per [this issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7424). But why the explicit calling syntax is not working the same way?

Comment: Again: *the decorator replaces the function.* The decorated `f1` could have _any_ arbitrary signature. It's not about the *calling*, it's about `f1` not being the `f1` that you wrote anymore.

Comment: @deceze assignment in second case does the same, `f2` could have arbitrary signature before being reassigned. This really doesn't explain this difference, and this is not the first time when I encounter `mypy` incompatible hadling of decorator vs explicit transform.